# The Direction of Borel Reducibility

Tags: equivalence-relations, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are Polish spaces and $E$ and $F$ are Borel equivalence relations on $X$ and $Y$, respectively, we say that $E$ is Borel reducible to $F$ if there exists a Borel function $f:X\to Y$ such that for all $x, x'\in X$, we have $xEx'$ if and only if $f(x)Ff(x')$. The idea is to express a certain fact that "$E$ is no more complicated than $F$". (See this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_equivalence_relation) for instance.) But why is $f$ from $X$ into $Y$ and not the other way around?

There are countless notions of reducibility in mathematics. Many of the notions invoke the existence of a function from one set to another, such as this one here. Other examples of such notions include Turing reducibility and so on. The "direction" of Turing reducibility is easy to grasp, but I am not sure why for Borel reducibility.

Comment: Assume $E$ is Borel reducible to $F$ and you are given the problem $P_E$ of deciding given $x$ and $x'$ whether they are $E$-equivalent. You can use a Borel reduction $f$ to compute $f(x)$ and $f(x')$ and then you have an instance of problem $P_F$: are $f(x)$ and $f(x')$ $F$-equivalent? So when $E$ is Borel reducible to $F$, then problem $P_E$ (Borel) reduces to prolem $P_F$. So assuming computing $f$ is somehow "easy" – which is the meaning of Borel here –: problem $P_E$ is no more complicated than problem $P_F$.

Comment: FWIW the right computability-theoretic analogue of Borel reductions is not Turing reducibility but **many-one reducibility** - ignoring the fact that it treats sets instead of equivalence relations (which we can overcome - look up "ceers"), the point is that computable functions are the analogue of Borel functions (and the fact that we have no $X$ and $Y$ just reflects the fact that the ambient space is always $\omega$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for pointing that out! Hope that will make my understanding better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following naive idea might help you. When a function $f:X\to Y$ is Borel? Whenever $f^{-1}(B)$ is Borel (in $X$) if $B$ is Borel (in $Y$). (Note that this does not 
 preclude “uglier” (non Borel) sets have “nice” preimages.) So the rough conclusion is that

> (*) preimages of sets are nicer that the sets themselves.

The same goes for [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadge_hierarchy), [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction)… So, no matter what you are reducing, if reductions are done through functions with a behavior like (*), the simpler side is on the domain.

To illustrate the point, you can work through the following exercise: *If $E$ is Borel-reducible to $F$ and $F$ has Borel equivalence classes, then so does $E$.*

The proof depends exactly on the assumption (*) (namely, Borel-measurability).